# Accept Certificate for SVN from BugTracker.Net

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, bug-tracking, bugtracker.net

I'm trying to integrate SVN with BugTracker.NET.
On the page that accesses SVN I get the error "Server certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted".
I'm using VisualSVN Server for the SVN server.

Comment: I think I understand the problem which is more generic and I can't find an easy solution.
The SVN client doesn't accept the server certificate, the SVN client is being ran from the web application with the ASPNET user, and I can't easly make the certificate permanently accepted for that user.
Also I think that if I knew how to export the certificate from VisualSVN Server and bring it to the machine where I have BugTracker.net the problem would be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

Open a cmd window on the bugtracker.net server. Write any svn command adding the svn option "--config-dir C:\whatever"
Accept permanently the certificate.

The user files will be saved in the C:\whatever directory

Then go to the bugtracker.net web.config file and add the same option to the SubversionAdditional args.
add key="SubversionAdditionalArgs" value="--config-dir c:\whatever"

And it will work fine forever since the IUSER_HOST windows user (ASP user) will use that cache directory and will find the file to trust the machine)

Answer (score 0):

Say you're trying to access

```
https://www.xyz.com/<whatever>
```

And the certificate has been issued to www.abc.com. Try

```
https://www.abc.com/<whatever>
```

And it should work.

Comment: It's true that the certificate was issue for the machine name and the client is using an external IP to access the machine, but even if I knew how to change the assigned name on the certificate, the client machine would not recognize it (I think). So I need to make the SVN client accept permanently the certificate for the ASPNET user.

Comment: Hey, I finally see something, after I deceived the client machine by changing the hosts file and using the SVN server name to connect to the SVN. Then by adding the argument "--trust-server-cert" BugTracker.NET is able to access SVN. it still bothers me to change the hosts file, but if there is no better solution I'll have to accept this one! Thanks.